# is it anti-pattern using not top-level fun in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm a beginner to jetpack compose.
Following codelabs, I found they teach me only using top-level function.
I can use the composable function in Activity, but I can't found whoever use this way.
I wanna know which is the best practice.

*my code*

```
class RecyclerViewActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp {
                Test()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun MyApp(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
        ComposeDemoTheme {
            content()
        }

    }
    @Composable
    fun Test() {
    
    }
}
```

*codelabs*

```
class RecyclerViewActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp {
                Test()
            }
        }
    }


}
    @Composable
    fun MyApp(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
        ComposeDemoTheme {
            content()
        }

    }
    @Composable
    fun Test() {
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expected to split your code by screens/views, and each screen/view is placed inside it's own file

Usually you don't wanna have any composables in you `Activity`. You can set theme and other context variables right inside `setContent` or move it to `MyApp` if you have too many logic, but in this case I'd stay you move this composable into `MyApp.kt` too

I usually do structure like this:

- screenName: package

  - Screen.kt
  - ScreenRow.kt: if screen has a list
  - ButtomBar.kt: if screen has buttom bar and the code is not trivial
  - ...

So usually when you see that you file contains too many composables you move logically independent parts into other files

Comment: thank you for your help. also I want to know one more. Do I need to use fragment in jetpack compose? I am confused whether to use frament or navigation.

Comment: @Charles no, you don't need fragments anymore, compose navigation is good